# Seeking understanding of the positional operator in the case of a single update of non-periodic time series segment

Tags: mongodb, python-3.x, pymongo

I'm experimenting with a schema for recording some *non-periodic* time series data using `pymongo`. There's a decent amount of stuff out there about *periodic* time series, but not too much for non-periodic. Taking a leaf from [this post](http://bluxte.net/musings/2015/01/21/efficient-storage-non-periodic-time-series-mongodb).

In this schema, the collection documents each contain fixed count of data/time points. I'm initializing a segment with something like:

```
nonTime = datetime.fromordinal(1)  #create a time we can use as an "invalid" time entry
segment = {
    'times': [nonTime] * 64,
    'values': [float('nan')]}
collection.insert(segment)
```

Armed with a beginners understanding of the `$` (*positional*) operator, I concocted the following update:

```
collection.update({'times': nonTime}, {'$set': {'times.$': now(), 'values.$': newValue}})
```

This works like a charm. I'm not sure how expensive the linear seek for the match is, but my data isn't so steady that I'm terribly worried about that part. It keeps the segments small and nice.

What I would like to do though is avoid adding `newValue` when the previous element is the same value. For example, if my segment looks like

```
{
    'times': [t1, t2, t3, nonTime, ... nonTime],
    'values': [42.0, 13.0, 42.0, nan, ... nan]}
```

I want to add a new t4/newValue only if newValue is not equal to that last 42.0 at slot 2 (zero indexed).

I tried the following largish expression on a lark:

```
collection.update({'$and': [{'times': nonTime}, {'values.$-1': {'$ne': newValue}}]}, {same_set_as_above})
```

Amazingly, it didn't blow up. But then... it didn't work either. It appended the duplicate 42.0 anyway. Am I just expecting too much of the positional operator? Is there a different way to do this? I was trying to keep it as a single transaction.